# Convert Multidimensional arrays as key and value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 Multidimensional arrays as follow:

Array1:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                       [0] => 2D Design 
                       [1] => 3D Design & Modeling) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => Android Developer 
                       [1] => Artificial Intelligence 
                       [2] => Web Developer)
       )
```

Array2:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                       [0] => 5 
                       [1] => 10) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 
                       [1] => 4 
                       [2] => 6)
       )
```

I want to combine the above 2 arrays as `key` and `value` as below.

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                       [2D Design] => 5 
                       [3D Design & Modeling] => 10 ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                       [Android Developer] => 2 
                       [Artificial Intelligence] => 4 
                       [Web Developer] => 6 )
      )
```

Please help me to do this. Answers will be appreciated.

Comment: use array_key and  array_values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  `array_combine()` function creates an array by using the elements from one "keys" array and one "values" array.

Note: Both arrays must have equal number of elements!

First parameter array taken as key of new array  and second parameter taken as value new array .

```
$new_array=array();

for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++)
{

   $new_array[$i]=array_combine($arr1[$i],$arr2[$i]); 
}

print_r($new_array);
```

**Output :**

```
 Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [2D Design] => 5
        [3D Design & Modeling] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Android Developer] => 2
        [Artificial Intelligence] => 4
        [Web Developer] => 6
    )

 )
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work,

```
$arr1 = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "2D Design",
        1 => "3D Design & Modeling"),
    1 => array(0 => "Android Developer",
        1            => "Artificial Intelligence",
        2            => "Web Developer",
    ),
);
$arr2 = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 5,
        1 => 10,
    ),
    1 => array(0 => 2,
        1            => 4,
        2            => 6,
    ),
);
$temp = [];
foreach ($arr1 as $k => &$v) {
    foreach ($v as $k1 => &$v1) {
        $temp[$k][$v1] = $arr2[$k][$k1];
    }
}
print_r($temp);
```

I have fetched values of first array `arr1` as key to `temp` variable and map it with values of `arr2`as value to `temp` array.
This code will work even if index i.e. 0,1,2,3 can be anything.

Here is working [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28c4e6d56136b041d7205239789e87659dcbd024).

Answer (score 0):

Simply make mapped calls of `array_combine()`.  So long as the same positioned rows have the same number of elements in them, everything will work perfectly.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vgmjW))

```
$keys =[
    ['2D Design', '3D Design & Modeling'],
    ['Android Developer', 'Artificial Intelligence', 'Web Developer']
];

$values = [
    [5, 10],
    [2, 4, 6]
];

var_export(
    array_map('array_combine', $keys, $values)
);
```